# How to add text to bottom of esttab table without using estadd

Tags: formatting, format, string-formatting, stata

The code below adds custom text to each equation using a local and produces what I want:

```
estimates clear
eststo clear
sysuse auto, clear

eststo w1: regress price mpg trunk length
estadd local number one
eststo w2: regress turn mpg trunk length
estadd local number two
eststo w3: regress displacement mpg trunk length
estadd local number three

esttab w1 w2 w3, stats(number)
```

However, I would like to be able to write the custom text in the `esttab` command syntax and not before using locals.

This is incorrect, but the option might look something like the following:

```
estimates clear
eststo clear
sysuse auto, clear

eststo w1: regress price mpg trunk length
eststo w2: regress turn mpg trunk length
eststo w3: regress displacement mpg trunk length

esttab w1 w2 w3, stats("number", "one" "two" "three")
```

Can I somehow insert an option to the `esttab` command where I spell out what I want? I know that there is an `indicate()` option, but I could not figure out if it can do what I need or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot define the contents of a `stats()` element on the fly.

However, a workaround is the following:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear
estimates clear

eststo w1: regress price mpg trunk length
eststo w2: regress turn mpg trunk length
eststo w3: regress displacement mpg trunk length

esttab, prefoot(`"{hline 60}"' ///
                `"numbers{dup 15: }one{dup 13: }two{dup 11: }three"' ///
                `"more numbers{dup 9: }four{dup 12: }five{dup 13: }six"') 

------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)             (3)   
                    price            turn    displacement   
------------------------------------------------------------
mpg                -173.7         -0.0656          -1.777   
                  (-1.97)         (-0.88)         (-1.04)   

trunk              -0.855         -0.0593          0.0659   
                  (-0.01)         (-0.66)          (0.03)   

length              21.40           0.165***        3.068***
                   (0.79)          (7.19)          (5.83)   

_cons              5854.0           10.76*         -342.3** 
                   (0.97)          (2.09)         (-2.92)   
------------------------------------------------------------
numbers               one             two           three
more numbers         four            five             six
N                      74              74              74   
------------------------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Obviously, you will have to specify every time the spaces according to your use case. You can do this manually or by writing a small program that calculates these.